# Can I duplicate a Layout changing inside Strings?

Tags: android, layout, styles

I'm triying to figure out how to duplicate a layout with information as many records I have.

In this App I want as many comments I have in the same boxes like the default comment, in this question i will make a simple for, to try it.
[image]

Here's how I have the layour distribution:

[image]

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     LinearLayout linlay = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext()); //ComentarioEjemplo
     LinearLayout head = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext()); //LinearLayout
     TextView num_com = new TextView(getApplicationContext()); //TextView
     TextView admin = new TextView(getApplicationContext()); //TextView5
     View separ = new View(getApplicationContext()); // Separador
     TextView coment = new TextView(getApplicationContext()); // TextView6



                    comentarios_layout.addView(linlay);

                    num_com.setText("com");
                    admin.setText("adn");
                    coment.setText("tasuhdfsadh kasjdh as");

                    // STYLE ///////////////////////////////////////////////
                    linlay.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d2d2d2"));
                    linlay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    head.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutLinlay = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutHead = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    layoutLinlay.setMargins(20, 5, 20, 5);

                    linlay.setLayoutParams(layoutLinlay);
                    head.setLayoutParams(layoutHead);

                    linlay.addView(head);
                    linlay.addView(separ);
                    linlay.addView(coment);

                    head.addView(num_com);
                    head.addView(admin);
}
```

I tried to change the style programming but im really struggling with it. Is there any simple way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this very easily using recycler views, you will have to design it once in xml and you can reuse that layout for multiple rows, check out this link for a more detailed answer https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465

Comment: I'm not a experienced programmer

Comment: I can not write the whole code for you, try it yourself and post your code if you are stuck at some point